# Get control index in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, controls

I've created a basic datagrid based on a HTML table, with each row containing a number of select controls. I can add new rows and controls (as arrays) dynamically but can't seem to work out how to get the index of a particular control in jquery when the change event fires. I'm using

```
$('#tblGrid').on('change', '.parentClass', function()
    {
    );
```

I need to use this to generate the content of another select control in the row (via ajax) as the options in it depend on the selection in the first control

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the html you can create a traverse .... first to the row...then use `find()` within the row

```
$('#tblGrid').on('change', '.parentClass', function(){
    // `this` inside any event handler is element event occured on
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var $otherselect = $row.find('.otherSelectClass').doSomething();       
});
```

Question is not very clear on what objective is with this other select